# Can't sign into Google account from Word using MS-OFBA

Tags: ms-office, webdav, google-account

I am implementing a custom WebDav server that will use [MS-OFBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sharepoint_protocols/ms-ofba/30c7bbe9-b284-421f-b866-4e7ed4866027) and allow users to sign in with their Google account.

I have it working with Microsoft accounts. When I try to implement Google account (using OAuth2), I get the following error from Word:

> Your organization's policies are preventing us from completing this action for you. For more info, please contact your help desk.

My computer is not joined to a domain, so this error message isn't accurate. Also, there are a lot of people who get this error by clicking a link from within an office application (and the fix is to update the registry), but this does not apply to me.

The best information I found so far from MSFT is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/authentication/not-render-a-custom-duo-api-multi-factor-authentication-login-page). I'm not sure if it is exactly the problem I'm having, but when I navigate to the page that is erroring inside Word but in a normal browser, there are 2 iframes, one goes to an endpoint on accounts.google.com and another one goes to an endpoint on a different domain (accounts.youtube.com).

I am able to duplicate the problem when I have Word navigate to a page on my custom site that has an iframe that isn't able to load (e.g., site indicates via headers it can't be shown inside an iframe). But if the iframe does load (regardless of if the src is from the same site or not), then it seems to work.